# aligning equations in smallmatrix environment

Tags: matrices

So for example, in the next code I get my equations in center aligment, I'd like to have them aligned to the left.

```
$(a_{2})_{pq}=\left \{ \begin{smallmatrix} (a_{1})_{pq} ,p\neq i \\ (ca_{1})_{pj}+(a_{1})_{pq},p\neq i \end{smallmatrix}\right.$
```

Note:  I'm using smallmatrix environmet so I can have my definition inline, I mean like being part of the same line.

Comment: `smallmatrix` is intended for setting matrices, for groups of equations you want something like `aligned`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the alignment as in `cases` by adding "fill" glue:

```
$(a_{2})_{pq}=
 \left\{
 \begin{smallmatrix}
   (a_{1})_{pq},\hfill&p\neq i\hfill\\
   (ca_{1})_{pj}+(a_{1})_{pq},\hfill& p\neq i\hfill
 \end{smallmatrix}\right.$
```

However, such constructs are best placed in a display. See the result as a witness.

[image]

Comment: This is pretty useful. It might be a good idea for the `amsmath` guide to mention this.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say use `cases`. (You need the `amsmath` package for this.)

Here an example:

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
(a_{2})_{pq}=
    \begin{cases}
    (a_{1})_{pq}               & p\neq i \\ 
    (ca_{1})_{pj}+(a_{1})_{pq} & p\neq i
    \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: The thing is that I'm using smallmatrix environmet so I can have my definition inline, I mean like being part of the same line. If I do this then my definition is not on the same line and it is not as small as it is produced by using smallmatrix environment.

Comment: Well, I guess you could just change ``\[...\]`` to ``$...$``.

Comment: Yes, Almost, except for the size.